# How to end if statement in Haml?

Tags: if-statement, haml

I want to conver this code into Haml, but without "end", whole table becomes a part of "else" condition, not only "tr". How to do this?

`

```
<% if line_item == @current_item %>
  <tr id="current_item">
<% else %>
  <tr>
<% end %>
    <td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
    <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
    <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %></td>
  </tr>
```

`

Comment: Dzięki, próbowałem, ale converter właśnie nie daje rady :/ podaje błędnie.

Answer (score 0):

Usually best to set just the attribute and not the whole tag in an `if` clause

```
%tr{id: line_item == @current_item ? 'current_item' : nil}
  %td #{line_item.quantity}&times;
  %td= line_item.product.title
  %td.item_price= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price)
```